# Adding an attribute to a class after the documentation comment trivia

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to turn

```
namespace DevComponents.WpfEditors.Primitives
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EditorFreeTextButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EditorFreeTextButton : EditorButton
    {
        public EditorFreeTextButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

into

```
namespace DevComponents.WpfEditors.Primitives
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EditorFreeTextButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    [System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    public partial class EditorFreeTextButton : EditorButton
    {
        public EditorFreeTextButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

through Roslyn. I have the following code that works

```
private static SyntaxNode AddAnnotation(ClassDeclarationSyntax classNode, SyntaxNode rootNode)
{
    var name = SyntaxFactory.ParseName("System.Reflection.Obfuscation");
    var arguments = SyntaxFactory.ParseAttributeArgumentList("(Exclude = true)");
    var attribute = SyntaxFactory.Attribute(name, arguments);
    var leadingTrivia = classNode.GetLeadingTrivia();
    var whitespace = leadingTrivia.LastOrDefault(x => x.Kind() == SyntaxKind.WhitespaceTrivia);

    var attributeList = SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(attribute))
        .WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.CarriageReturnLineFeed);
    var newClassNode = classNode.WithoutLeadingTrivia()
        .WithLeadingTrivia(whitespace)
        .AddAttributeLists(attributeList)
        .WithLeadingTrivia(leadingTrivia);

    rootNode = rootNode.ReplaceNode(classNode, newClassNode);
    return rootNode;
}
```

However I feel like I am coding in circles to get all the leading Trivia right.

Is there a easier way to insert an attribute to be after the `SingleLineDocumentationCommentTrivia` and be formatted correctly with the correct leading whitespace trivia?

Comment: @Hosch250 I think i misread what you said before I commented and you did not use the function I think you where using. Please undelete your answer so I can look in to and ask you about `Formatter.Annotation` more.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I missed your notification.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `WithAnnotation(Formatter.Annotation)` member.  This should create a new node with the correct leading indentation.

```
var newClassNode = classNode.AddAttributeLists(attributeList)
                            .WithAnnotation(Formatter.Annotation)
```

Comment: That puts the annotation before the `SingleLineDocumentationCommentTrivia`. however the `Formatter.Annotation` might be useful

Comment: OK, I'll delete this then.